# How do I solve this congruence problem?

Tags: number-theory

I have so far this:

I have the following question:

Find all solutions $x^2\equiv 7 (\mod 143).$
This is what I did :

$11,13$ are primes, therefore :

(1) $x^2\equiv 7(\mod 11)$
(2) $x^2\equiv 7(\mod 13)$

Comment: Next step: find all solutions, if any, of $x^2\equiv7\pmod{11}$, probably by trial and error.

Comment: I tried brute force if there is solution. I can't find myself helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The congruence $x^2\equiv 7\pmod{11}$ has no solution.

This can be set by using the Legendre symbol or simply by looking at the residuals

Answer (score 0):

$\begin{align}\bmod 11\!:\  &\left[x^{\large 2} \equiv -2^{\large 2}\right]^{\large 5}\\[.2em]
\Rightarrow\ \ 1\equiv\ &x^{\large 10}\equiv -2^{\large 10}\equiv -1\ \Rightarrow\!\Leftarrow\end{align}$